# 16Hertz Uno R3 Board vs Arduino Uno R3 Board

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, atmega328

I bought a [16Hertz Uno R3 Board](http://www.16hertz.com/product/uno-r3-kit-ultimate-arduino-compatible/). When I installed the driver and the Arduino IDE,  in the IDE`s menu I saw:

> Tools -> Board -> Arduino Uno

was selected by default which is great, but...

> Tools -> Port -> COM3(Arduino Mega or Mega 2560)

was selected by default which I think might be some kind of misunderstanding...

When I chose:

> Tools -> Board -> Arduino Mega or Mega 2560

On that tools menu appeared new menu "Processor" with two options:

> Tools -> Processor -> ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)

which was selected by default and there was another option

> Tools -> Processor -> ATmega1280

When I restore Tools -> Board settings back to "Arduino Uno" the "Processor" menu with the two options disappeared and Tools -> Port setting did not changed!

If you take my board and look at the Microcontroller there is written:

> ATMEGA328P-PU

Also on that board is written:

> 16HzUNO

I need to know:

1. What does 16Hz mean? Does it mean the clock or frequency of this
   Microcontroller? I think it does not, if I try to find out details of my Microcontroller on the [rs-online site](http://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/microcontrollers/6962260/), there is written:

> ATMEGA328P-PU, 8 bit AVR Microcontroller 20MHz 1 kB, 32 kB Flash, 2
>   kB RAM, I2C 28-Pin PDIP

2. Why was there "COM3(Arduino Mega or Mega 2560)" written on the
   Port's menu?
3. Is my 16Hz Uno R3 and the Arduino Uno R3 board the same? Which one
   is better? When one of those is better?
4. Does the standard Arduino Uno R3 board have the same ATMEGA328P-PU
   Microcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a look at the [Arduino comparison table](http://arduino.cc/en/Products.Compare). This shows that *all* Arduino Uno boards run at 16 MHz. It seems that you have fallen for the marketing on the [page for the Uno kit](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104015236/http://www.16hertz.com/product/uno-r3-kit-ultimate-arduino-compatible/) that you provided.

Also, which version of the IDE are you running? You should upgrade to the latest version, which is currently, at the time of writing, version 1.6.1.

To answer your questions in turn:

1. "**16Hz**" is the *brand name* and has nothing whatsoever to do
   with the speed, which is actually 16 **Mega** Hertz. "Clock" and
   "Frequency" refer to the same thing. 16 MHz is the clock frequency
   of the board, and is the speed at which the **ATmega328** runs at.
   The RS Online link does indeed state 20 MHz, but that is merely the
   *maximum* speed at which the **ATmega328** can run at. The Uno under clocks it at 16 MHz.
2. The **Ports** menu will show you a number of possible devices, **Arduino Uno** should be one of them (which is the one you should select) and three items below that will be **Arduino Mega or Mega 2560** (which you should ignore, you do not have a Mega board<sup>1</sup>). Unfortunately the Arduino site only shows the Mac menu, even on [the Windows guide](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows#toc7)

   > [image: Mac Arduino Tools menu]

   which is no help to you, assuming that you are running the Arduino IDE on Windows. You should actually see this in the **Board** menu:

   > [image: Windows Arduino Tools Board menu]

   and this in the **Port** menu:

   > [image: Windows Arduino Tools Port menu]

   As you can see, there should be no mention of the microcontroller in the **Port** menu.
3. The 16Hz branded Uno and the Arduino Uno are to all intents and purposes the same and as I state in the first line, the 16 MHz Uno is *exactly* the same as a regular Uno, it is just marketing.
4. Both the 16Hz and the Arduino Uno have a **ATmega328** and the Mega board has a **ATmega2560**. Again, check the [Arduino comparison table](http://arduino.cc/en/Products.Compare) to see the variety of the boards and their respective microcontrollers.

I hope that answers your questions.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you *do* chose the **Arduino Mega or Mega 2560** option, in the **Board** menu, then indeed there will be an additional **Processor** menu. However, this is irrelevant in your case, as you do not have a Mega board, and so you need to chose the Uno in the **Board** menu. If you do so, then the **Processor** menu will disappear, as it is not needed for the Uno.

Answer (score 2):

1. Every Arduino is using a quartz crystal in order to get the frequency needed. ATmega328 can handle up to 20 MHz
2. ??
3. Yes. You can't run the microcontroller by itself. It has an internal oscillator but none is using it. So basically you will have a 16 MHz crystal.
4. Pretty much the Arduino Uno, Nano, Mini and few others have the ATmega328P.
   Note that the `-PU` `-AU` at the end defines the package. So they're the same.

Arduino Mega, Leonardo, Micro, Due use other chips.

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory for 2:

The text that shows up in the Tools > Port list after the COMx

eg `Tools -> Port -> COM3(Arduino Mega or Mega 2560)`

is simply what the IDE thinks the board is based on the USB ID (VID/PID) of the board's USB interface chip. For some clones, this is blank because they don't even use the same chip as an authentic Uno. In your case, I would suspect that they have used the USB chip from a Mega board on your Uno board.

So the IDE thinks a Mega is attached because it is seeing a USB chip from a Mega, even though it is an Uno (clone).